# Не отображается background когда задаю его в классе через css

Tags: html, css, css3

```css
.impressed{
 background-image: url(img\BG.png) no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="impressed">

</div>
```

Вставил основной код, при создании в div тега img картинка добавляется, причем путь один и тот же, и пишу его правильно. Но когда задал напрямую в header, все работает, но мне нужно именно в классе задать background.Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Проблемой оказаось то, что когда задаете background-image: url(img\BG.png); делая это в классе, то нужно задавать ему и высоту, тк как по непонятным причинам, высота равна 0 по дэфолту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `background-image` только задает картинку, за повторение изображения отвечает другое свойство - `background-repeat`. Можно все свойства писать в одном, но для этого нужно использовать свойство `background`

```css
.impressed {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50x50);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="impressed">

</div>
```

Comment: у меня даже картинка не отображается, не говоря уже о том чтобы растянуть ее на весь экран

Comment: @АлександрПогребняк значит неправильно прописан путь

Comment: аналогичный путь прописан в header, в том же css файле, но когда записываю в классе, не выводит. Приходиться создавать тег img, что в моем случае мне не подходит